date time formating in snowflake
In source file, there is date and time format like this 20240415114349 after ingestion into snowflake database it changes and become like this 2611-05-25 01:48:44.449. I need only YYYY-DD-MM HH-MM-SS and correct ones. As data type in SF, iam using TIMESTAMPNTZ. For ingestion i'am using AF and my config.json looks like this:
   "files":[
      {
         "table_name": "CDR_CBG",
         "file_pattern":"cdl_%Y%m%d*",
         "partition_pattern":"%Y/%m/%d",
         "active": "true",
         "fail_on_missing_files": "true",
         "overwrite_target":"false",
         "move_files":"true",
         "file_dt_expr" : "",
         "dt_col_format" : "",
         "target_partition_adjustment":"1",
         "dbt_snapshot": "",
         "snowflake_table": "CDR_CBG"
      }
   ]


Hi - please update your question with detailed information about how you are ingesting the data. Assuming you are using a COPY INTO statement then include that statement; if you are using a defined file format, then include the DDL for that file format, etc

I'm guessing that you need to set dt_col_format to match your source date format

Tried that "YYYYMMDDHH24MISS", still wrong ;/
